# Minko alpha blended mesh behind additive blended mesh

Tags: actionscript-3, minko

I'm trying to display a blended lightbeam mesh in front of my alpha blended meshes and additive blending erases them, opaque materials are displayed correctly. Anyone had a similar issue

[image: Problem screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps you should provide more details on how you do this, such that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by making a little hack, ive found out that if you add objects to scene per script, static stage objects coming from minko studio tend to cause this problem. my solution was to make the lighbeam a very big particle and it worked as both the circle under the mesh and lightbeam were now added through script